# How to preserve the stickers of windows xp and mobile centrino on the laptop

Tags: laptop

As time passess they come off. How should I preserve it? Can I rip them off some how and keep them safe? Are they available in the market

Comment: they are useless )

Comment: not where i live,

Comment: @user39966: What do you mean? Why do you not think they are useless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main concern should be ruining the surface underneath.  If you end up selling the laptop 5 years down the road, I doubt anyone buying a used laptop will care about the stickers.  Though if the surface is all scuffed up they might care.

Check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/15538/how-do-i-safely-remove-the-intel-and-windows-stickers-on-my-laptop) for how to remove them without ruining the surface.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider painting them over with a clear nail polish. That should help preserve them.

Comment: what will happen when the nail polish starts to come off! the sticker come off two if it gets stuck with the polish!

Comment: Nail Polish won't come off in pieces. Of course, it can always be re-applied. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You can buy them on eBay.

[Windows XP Stickers](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/2pcs-New-Genuine-Windows-XP-Vista-stickers-/270645059475?pt=UK_Computing_DesktopComponents_RL&hash=item3f03b3df93)

[Centrino Stickers](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/Original-Intel-Centrino-2-vPro-Sticker-16-x-20mm-58-/350226770800?pt=UK_Computing_LaptopAccess_RL&hash=item518b246b70)

I actually take them off on new laptops, as otherwise the areas underneath them do not wear like the surroundings, so they leave a visible area that is not smooth when they finally disintegrate.

[Goo Gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJgF9.jpg) is the best stuff to safely take them off.

Answer (score 1):

One could argue that the stickers should be left in place to keep the laptop as originial as possible, it proves (to some degree, I know you can remove a sticker and put a new one on) what processor and OS came with the PC and such...I like them, but maybe that's just me...

Answer (score 1):

Just put clear tough plastic on the sticker and then put some clear tape on the plastic.