# How do I remove the glue left behind by those intel stickers?

Tags: laptop

I hate those intel stickers. So, being the idiot I am, just tried yanking it off.

Now, a ton of glue is left behind. I've tried (for about 2 hours) rubbing it with a damp cloth. It made a slight difference. But nothing significant.

Without buying any cleaning solution, how can I remove the glue?

And for the record, I have tried googling this. All the answers had to do with buying some clearner or were instructions on how to remove the sticker. I did find one thing (Put the sticker down again and the glue will want to follow it) but that did nothing.

Comment: use a rubber...

Comment: Consider searching instructables.com for a home remedy. Could save you from a store purchase. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution really is the best method. [Goo Gone works great](http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/GOO-GONE-Oven-CleanerSize-14-ozFragrance-39F167?gclid=CKKU1azmh7cCFccw4Aod-xIA5w&cm_mmc=PPC:GooglePLA-_-Cleaning-_-Chemicals-_-39F167&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=39F167&ef_id=moRQQ8YqzC4AAFp@:20130509004737:s)

Alternatives:

- Vineager
- Dish Soap
- Water
- Fingernail polish remover
- Paint Thinner
- Alcohol

What you want to avoid is anything abrasive, or it will leave scratches on the surface. So no baking soda, scratch pads etc.

But for a few dollars for a small bottle I would go with goo gone. It has a thousand uses outside of removing those glue patch residue spots.

Comment: I managed to find some GooGone in my pantry. Thanks!

Comment: I downvoted, because you list some _very_ good solvents like ,Paint Thinner' and 'Fingernal polish remover`. I don't know about the ingredients in the US, but in Europe the latter often (if not ever) includes acetone. With this you could ruin a lot of different sorts of plastic materials immediately. I also wouldn't use corrosive substances like acids on my computer. Personally I made the best experiences with oily solutions or alcohol (ethanol or isopropanol), although the latter can harm especially velvety surfaces. So as recommended by others: _Always test on a small, hidden area first!_

Comment: Fingernail polish remover is usually the best thing to use (it's usually acetone based). Though I did manage to "melt" the plastic a bit trying to clean the inside of my Roomba robot vacuum cleaner with it. Not sure I want to risk the plastic on a new laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use some kind of cleaning product, if trying duct tape doesn't help:

1. If rubbing doesn't help, try using duct tape or other very sticky tape to remove the remaining residue. Break or cut off a piece of tape, apply it to the surface, then remove it. Repeat this until all of the residue has been removed, and attached to the tape instead.
2. If all previous attempts fail, use chemicals. A popular and extremely useful method is to use a citric-acid based cleaner such as "Goo-Gone". These type of cleaners will not harm metal or harder plastics, but may dry the surface of softer plastics, leaving a white, frosted appearance. Test this on a small, hidden area first. Another liquid to try is alcohol. Another is WD-40 which won't hurt the surface and can be cleaned off the computer's surface with a dish rag and a little soap.

Taken from: [What is the right procedure to safely remove stickers from a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/15538/what-is-the-right-procedure-to-safely-remove-stickers-from-a-laptop?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Eucalyptus oil, this removes all of those paper label sticky glues

Answer (score 0):

Pour something alcoholic onto a cloth and hold it on the glue.  The alcohol should slowly dissolve the glue.

Alternatively, you can use hot water to melt the glue.  Boil some water, dip a cloth in it and   hold it to the glue.  Wipe and repeat until the glue is gone.

Comment: The hot water idea was able to spread it around a bit. I'll try the alcohol soon. I read online it's a bad idea though.

Comment: It depends on the surface you are using it on.  On plastic, it should be fine.